# iPhone -Remove the underline from link in UILabel

Tags: ios, iphone, hyperlink, uilabel, tttattributedlabel

I am using TTTAttributedLabel (https://github.com/twotoasters/TTTAttributedLabel). Here I'm correctly getting the label with some clickable text.

[image]

I need to display my text like the username in above image(ie. without underline).How could I do that?

Comment: comment  [self.summaryLabel addLinkToURL:url withRange:linkRange]; and try. As addLinkToURL method make underline in the text. It may help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code (sorry for formatting, written on phone...)

```
NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleNone] : (id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName};
self.label.linkAttributes = linkAttributes;
```

Comment: Its working 100% in TTTAttributedLabel and it might also work for UILabel

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4.0

```
   let LinkAttributes = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: testLink.linkAttributes)
   LinkAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle] =  NSNumber(value: false)
   yourLabel.linkAttributes = LinkAttributes as NSDictionary as! [AnyHashable: Any]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are already having label with underline style and if you want to remove it programatically use the following code

```
 let string = "your text"
 let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
            ]
 let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string, 
 attributes: attributes)
 yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```